# How do i know which file is causing Error

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am getting the following Error in Angular APP how do i find out which Script or file is causing the Error. using JQuery 2.1

```
  ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:2538), <anonymous>:286:5)
    at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:26925)
    at Object.k.add [as done] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:27234)
    at n.fn.ready (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:29340)
    at n.fn.init (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:24425)
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:405)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:2538), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (native)
    at Function.n.extend.globalEval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2:2538)
    at n.fn.extend.domManip (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:3:17225) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: Which all js files has `$scope` used? Hopefully `app.js`..

Comment: please provide your html and controller